# Split datatable to list object C# using LINQ or Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datatable

I have a datatable which contains some rows as a result of joining two tables using the below query:

```
SELECT 
    e.Id AS EmpId,
    e.Name AS EmpName,
    d.Id AS DeptId,
    d.Name AS DeptName
FROM  
    Departments D
JOIN 
    Employees E ON D.Id = E.DeptId
```

[image]

On the other hand, I have these classes:

```
class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int DeptId { get; set; }
}

class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

So, how can I convert the given datatable to a list of `Departments`, and each department has its own list of employees and so on ...

The basic solution which does the same requirement, it could be as follows, but it is not a professional one and it might hit the performance with big amount of data, especially if we are talking about multiple joins, not like the provided simple example:

```
var depts = new List<Department>();
var view = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "DeptId", "DeptName");
foreach (DataRow row in view.Rows)
{
    var dep = new Department();
    var depEmployees = new List<Employee>();
    dep.Id = int.Parse(row["DeptId"].ToString());
    dep.Name = row["DeptName"].ToString();
    foreach (var emp in dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(w => int.Parse(w["DeptId"].ToString()) == dep.Id).ToList())
    {
        depEmployees.Add(new Employee
        {
            Id = int.Parse(emp["EmpId"].ToString()),
            Name = emp["EmpName"].ToString(),
            City = emp["City"].ToString(),
            DeptId = dep.Id
        });
        dep.Employees = depEmployees;
    }

    depts.Add(dep);
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you know, that SO is not a code-writing service? It would be great if you show some of your code or search efforts.

Comment: @vasily.sib as you can see my DataTable contains an SQL result set which represents a JOIN between two tables in the database, what I exactly need here is to convert that datatable with the shown result set to the given DTO classes instead of the flat view of the datatable to be looked like the Entity Framework which helps me to work on each entity alone and dig deeply with nested objects ... got my point?
I can get each table data in a separate datatable, then fill the list using LINQ, but I need to do it after getting the data through JOIN ...

Comment: Why do you use datatable and raw sql query if you have Entity Framework?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov this is an old application I am working on and it uses many datatables with classic ADO, in addition, it uses many `RowFilter`s which makes you lost while debugging, so, I thought about to convert the huge datatable to an DTO which contains the nested DTOs which I need, then, I can do what I want easily

Answer (score 2):

How about this solution:

```
var view = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "DeptId", "DeptName");
var departments = view.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
    .ToLookup(row => row["DeptId"])
    .Select(group => new Depatment
        {
            Id = group.Key, // convert somehow
            Name = group.First()["DeptName"], // convert somehow
            Employees = group.Selec(row => new Employee
            {
                Id = row["EmpId"], // convert somehow
                Name = row["EmpName"] // convert somehow
            }).ToList();
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: I got your idea, but the code has an issue as there is no implementation for `ToLookup` with `DataTable` ... but this kind of grouping works fine for me... on the other hand, what do you think about the performance?

Comment: You where right. `Rows` not implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, so you need a `OfType<T>()` (or `Cast<T>()`) call. As of performance, this should be fast enough. You can test it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
IList<Department> departments =
        table.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(d => new
        {
            Id = d.Field<Int32>("DeptId"),
            Name = d.Field<String>("DeptName")
        })
        .Select(grp =>
            new Department
            {
                Id = grp.Key.Id,
                Name = grp.Key.Name
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: It doesn't work .. it gives **Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access**

Comment: @Ahmed Negm Ok I update it can you try if its working for you now

Comment: it will not work, because it is not allowed to convert collection of `DataRow` to a collection of `Department`

Comment: This will return a list with the departments

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
           List<DataTable> deptTables = dt
                .AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("DeptId"))
                .Select(x => x.CopyToDataTable())
                .ToList();
```

---

Or create a dictionary

```
            Dictionary<int, DataTable> deptDict = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("DeptId"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.CopyToDataTable());
```